# inconsistent results from rails console v. dev UX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service, console, development-environment, cloud9-ide

Upon creation of a List of Quantities, the List attribute `total_calories` should be updated with the sum of all `calories` associated with the List. Lists and Foods are associated `has_many :through` Quantities, and each Food has a `calories` attribute.

When I create a List in the rails development user interface hosted by c9.io, it behaves as expected. When I create a List in the console, it does not; `total_calories` does not get updated. How could this be?

I would appreciate any tips about what to investigate, as I have never encountered this issue of inconsistency between the console and development user interface.

The service object `count_calories.rb`:

```
class CountCalories

  def initialize(list)
    @list=list
  end

  def count
    @calories = 0
    @list.quantities.each do |q|
      @calories += Food.find(q.food_id).calories
    end
    @list.update!(total_calories: @calories)
    @list.save!
  end

end
```

The create method in the List controller:

```
def create
  @list = WriteList.new(list_params).write
  if @list.save
    flash[:success] = "A list has been created!"
    CountCalories.new(@list).count
    redirect_to @list
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

The service object `write_list.rb`, in case it is helpful:

```
class WriteList

  def initialize(params)
    @params=params
  end

  def write
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      list = List.new(days: @params[:days], name: @params[:name])
      list.save!
      3.times do
        food1 = Food.all.sample.id
        Quantity.create!(food_id: food1, list_id: list[:id], amount: 1+rand(6))
      end
      list.save!
      return list
    end
    rescue
      return List.new(days: @params[:days], name: @params[:name])
  end

end
```

The only thing I can think of is that maybe it has something to do with the migration to create total_calories:

```
class AddTotalCaloriesToLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :lists, :total_calories, :integer, :default => 0
  end
end
```

But mostly, I am baffled and would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have over engineered your problem.  It appears you are coming from a Java web stack and it's done differently in the rails way.  Avoid service objects if you don't need them.

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :calories

  has_many :lists, through: :food_lists, :dependent: :destroy
end

class FoodList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :food
  belongs_to :list
  validates_presence_of: :amount, :food, :list
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :food_lists
  has_many :foods, through: :food_lists, dependent: :destroy

  def total_calories
    self.food_lists.map{|fl| fl.amount * fl.food.calories}.sum
  end
end
```

Things that can be calculated on the fly, should be calculated,  only store them as a form of optimization if you really really need to.  It makes your business domain much easier to debug and support.  Maintaining state is a last resort!

Comment: THANK YOU @ilan for your enlightening and instructive answer. You even included `amount`, to my delight. I still am learning where to put things and trying to keep my models and controllers slim (as you've seen from my other questions/answers), but point taken about services. You're right that I had no need to store those values, and that was not even my aim. Seems like the biggest challenge for a rails n00b is knowing _where_ to put logic. For the record, I'm not really coming from any stack (it is all new), so I take your Java remark as a strange sort of compliment. ;)

Comment: @Leo, no problem, keep plugging away at it as you are and it will all work out.  The java stack was not an insult. It was a style of coding in which service objects were leveraged due to the limitations of Java Beans.  It was shown over years to be an anti pattern but it's still fairly common.

Comment: Interesting re: beans, thank you for explaining. I will keep plugging!

Comment: I have removed my acceptance of your answer because in my excitement about the leaner and more efficient code, I didn't notice that my original problem persisted. Still in the console when I create a new list, `total_calories` equals 0; whereas when I create a list through the c9.io dev user interface, `total_calories` behaves as expected. Any thoughts on how to track down this strange apparently error-free behavior?

Comment: I've identified the problem if not yet the answer: Quantities get added to a List via the write_list service, which is called by the List controller, which only happens when the List is created through the user interface. In the console, there is no addlist form, and hence no Quantity creation! I may refactor by moving Quantity creation to a callback in the List model to ensure that empty Lists are never created, depending on whether I decide that Quantity addition is essential to List creation or not. I have to think about that as a design issue. Anyway, I think now I am on the right track.